# Start VBA procedure AFTER load external data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple excel workbook with one sheet where is a query loaded after start workbook. **It isn't** VBA procedure.

Is it possible to start VBA procedure **after** external data is loaded?

Or is it possible to start macro after start Excel but wait until the query is finished?

Comment: `Or is it possible to start macro after start Excel but wait until the query is finished?` I think this one is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this as commented using `Workbook_Open` event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Me.RefreshAll
    DoEvents 'This will halt macro to allow the system finish on-going activity which is refreshing the workbook.
    MyMacro 'This is the name of the VBA procedure stored in a module you want to run

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I understand it well, but MyMacro is started immediatelly after workbook is opened. Before loading of external data.....

Comment: What did you use loading your external data? And where's your data coming from? I assumed you used a query linked from a database.

Comment: Yes, it's really query linked from database.. and office 2010

Comment: Hmmm... strange. But upon opening, does it update? Can you describe a bit more of what's happening  in the worksheet? I have no way of re-creating the same scenario as yours.

Comment: It works in XLS file, but not in XLT (I don't know why) - anyway, your Sub works! Thank you